# Efficiently convert a vector of bin counts to a vector of bin indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, scipy

I have a vector corresponding to the number of events occurring in a sequence of time bins. I need to obtain a vector containing the time bin indices for each event.

It's quite simple to do this with an ordinary Python loop:

```
import numpy as np

def bincounts2indices(bincounts):
    indices = tuple()
    for ii, count in enumerate(bincounts):
        indices += (ii,) * count
    return np.array(indices)

x = np.array([2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2])

print bincounts2indices(x)
# [0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 8 9 9]
```

Unfortunately this is a bit of a bottleneck in my code at the moment. I could use something like Cython or Numba to speed it up, but this seems like overkill and I'd prefer not to add extra dependencies.

Is anyone aware of a pure numpy/scipy way to do this efficiently?

Comment: [`np.repeat(np.arange(len(bins)), bins)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

Comment: @behzad.nouri whelp, that was simple. thanks.